# creation of login page along with authentication sapui5 by storing data in json and comparing json values with user input values

Tags: sapui5

*View1.view.xml*

```
<mvc:View xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="Login.controller.View1">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page title="Login">
                <f:SimpleForm maxContainerCols="2" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanL="4" labelSpanM="4" emptySpanL="0" emptySpanM="0" columnsL="2" columnsM="2">
                    <f:content>
                        <Input width="100%" id="__input0" placeholder="UserID" liveChange="true" />
                        <Input width="100%" id="__input1" type="Password" placeholder="Password" />
                        <Button text="Login" width="100px" id="__button0" type="Accept" press="Validation" />
                    </f:content>
                </f:SimpleForm>
                <Table items="{ path: '/Item' }" id="tableID" width="90%">
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem counter="0" id="__item0">
                            <cells>
                                <Text id="a1" text="{OrderID}" />
                                <Text text="{Quantity}" />
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                    <columns>
                        <Column id="__column0">
                            <header>
                                <Label text="OrderID" id="__label0" />
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column id="__column1">
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Quantity" id="__label1" />
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                </Table>
                <content/>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

*view1.controller.js*

```
 sap.ui.define(["sap/m/MessageToast",
     "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", 'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
 ], function(MessageToast, Controller, JSONModel) {
     "use strict";

     return Controller.extend("Login.controller.View1", {

         onInit: function(oEvent) {
             // set explored app's demo model on this sample
             var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("Login", "/model/Products.json"));
             sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
             this.getView().byId("tableID").setModel(oModel);
             // this.getView().byId("samplepie").setModel(oModel);
         },

         Validation: function() {
             var UserID = this.getView().byId("__input0").getValue();
             var Password = this.getView().byId("__input1").getValue();
             if (UserID == "") {
                 MessageToast.show("Please Enter UserID");
                 return false;
             } else if (Password == "") {
                 MessageToast.show("Please Enter Password");
                 return false;
             } else if (UserID == sap.ui.getCore().byId("a1").getValue()) {
                 MessageToast.show("authenticated ");
             }
         }

     });

 });
```

*products.json*

```
{
    "Item": [{
            "OrderID": "1100M",

            "Quantity": 100
        }, {
            "OrderID": "11001I",

            "Quantity": 250
        },

        {
            "OrderID": "11002D",

            "Quantity": 400
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried this code for login along with authentication but am getting error as `getValue` not defined when i used to fetch `JSON` values from view to controller,can anyone please give a solution?

Comment: So, how does your `Validation` method code looks like?

Comment: `sap.ui.getCore().byId("a1").getValue()` will throw an error as "a1" is the id of a `Text` not an `Input`. You have to use `getText()` to read the displayed string.

Comment: Not only is "a1" a Text control, it is also part of an aggregation `/Items` so there could be more of these (and remember, an ID can only be used once!) Better use databinding and model data instead of `getValue() / getText()`